# Pandas Dataframe error - Empty dataframe message

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV file, perform some filtering and save it as text document

```
Item Code Company
A    AAA   X
B    BBB   X
C    CCC   Y
D    DDD   Y
E    EEE   Y
```

I wrote a program to sort the item and code company-wise and save it to its corresponding txt file

```
a=list(set(df['Company']))
print(a)

for i in a:
    m=df.loc[df['Company'] == i]
    print(m)
    df= pd.DataFrame(m)
    df.to_csv(i+".txt", index=False)
```

My output is

```
['X', 'Y', 'Z']
   Item  Code Company
0    A    AAA    X
1    B    BBB     X
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Item, Code, Company]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Item, Code, Company]
Index: []
```

I have 3 txt outputs but only X.txt has data, Y and Z is empty. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are overwriting the `df` variable inside your loop

Comment: Oh yea, rookie mistake.
I did `df1=df` and reset the value of df at  the end of the loop. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I am sorry I couldnt upvote your answer, My reputation is under15 :(

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I modified the `df` val in the loop. I changed my code to

```
df1=df
a=df['Company'].unique()
print(a)

for i in a:
    print(df1.loc[df['Company'] == i])
    m=df1.loc[df['Company'] == i]
    print(m)
    df1= pd.DataFrame(m)
    df1.to_csv(i+".txt", index=False)
    df1=df
```

and it worked